# Converting equations to images

Tags: graphics, equations, pdf, texmaker

I am looking to convert LaTeX equations to images in the `pdf` output. After searching around here I've found some sources to websites and software that can convert *individual* equations to images, but it would be really nice if I could run such a converter on an entire `tex` file and have it convert the equations to images automatically. It's tedious to manually convert every equation only to plug them back into the document as an image.

```
\subsection{Linear equation through a point given its gradient}
A very simple differential equation is to find a linear equation through a particular point $P(x_i,y_i)$ given its gradient $k_i$ (or more commonly used for lines, its slope).

\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dx} = k_i \iff \int dy = \int k_i \cdot dx \iff y = k_i \cdot x + C
\end{equation}

Plug in the initial conditions to find the particular value of the constant of integration $C$.
```

Here's the default output where equations contain selectable text (in Acrobat Reader):

[image: Current pdf output: equation contains text]

But I was wondering if it was possible to output a `pdf` where the equations are converted to images like this (in Acrobat Reader):

[image: Desired pdf output: equation is printed as image]

*Note: Initially, I had asked a [different question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537033/converting-tables-and-equations-to-images) but then I decided to reword it significantly. As a result, the comments and answer aren't actually relevant to that older question anymore. I decided to re-post the revised version as a new question.*

Comment: Please do not mark this question as a duplicate of [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/537033/converting-tables-and-equations-to-images). Instead, please go to the older question and flag it to get it deleted.

Comment: You should be able to go to your prior question and hit the delete button at the bottom of the question.  That would be the easiest way.  Or else you could edit the former question (since it does not yet have answers) to reflect the content of this question.  That way the former comments would be preserved.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I understand, but someone took the time and effort to post an answer to the original question before I edited it, so I'm not sure if it's justified if I delete the question myself.

Comment: Got it.  I hadn't seen that initially.  If that answer answered the question *as written* (even if it was not what you meant), you should consider "accepting" the answer, with this question as a follow up.  If that answer misunderstood the question *as written*, then deleting it is OK.

Comment: So is your goal to be able to open the pdf in Word without messing up the equations (as implied by your previous question)? If not, then what is the reason that you want to do this?

Comment: @Marijn Images are easier to share with others if you don't want to share the entire pdf. The pdf to doc thing is only a secondary concern, but having images for equations would make the conversion a lot more reliable.

Comment: @JansthcirlU if you just want all the equations as image files then `make4ht yourfile.tex` (as mentioned in a comment to your previous question) will do that, it generates a html page (that you don't need) and a set of `.png` files, one file for each equation.

Comment: So there's no way to automatically render a pdf with the equations embedded as images? I'd have to manually replace all the equations by the images generated by `make4ht`?

Comment: There might be a way, just that you said you wanted to share the images with others and not the rest of the pdf, for that scenario `make4ht` is a quick solution.

Comment: And if you do want to share the pdf, then you can just share the pdf with regular equations, I presume?

Comment: Well, I just gave it a shot and the HTML has some weird combinations of text and images. For example, the equation $V = \frac{m}{\rho}$ renders "V =" as text but the fraction as an image. Maybe that's something I can tweak but I'd have to consult the documentation.

Comment: Regardless, my train of thought was to get a pdf with embedded images. If I then wanted to share an equation, I could just scroll to the right image in my pdf and copy it over. And frankly, I shouldn't justify why I'm curious about whether or not it's possible to convert equations to images when rendering a document.

Comment: You don't have to justify anything, it is just that finding the exact reason somebody has for wanting some functionality usually helps in giving advice, and might prevent people from doing unnecessary complicated things. In this case maybe you consider using tools that make screenshots, for every platform there are tools that you can configure to select an area of the screen and copy that to the clipboard (or save it as a new file if you want to keep it).

Comment: That's a fair point, my bad. But from what I gather this simply isn't possible using `tex`  or Texmaker alone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is to put each equation inside a `tikzpicture` and then use `tikzexternalize` to automatically convert each equation to png and include that png, similar to [tikz external use png as default instead of pdf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74605/tikz-external-use-png-as-default-instead-of-pdf). The implementation below requires that you replace `\begin{equation}\end{equation}` with the new command `\pngequation`.

This needs to be compiled with `-shell-escape`. Note that the compiler to create the images is hardcoded, in this case `pdflatex`, which can be modified if you want another compiler.

Note that this is only a proof on concept. It is rather roundabout, very likely has limitations, problems and/or side effects, and is therefore not recommended - for most use cases there will be easier solutions as mentioned in the comments.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\tikzset{%
    % Add size information to the .dpth file (png is in density not size)
    /pgf/images/external info,
    % Use the png export AND the import
    use png/.style={png export,png import},
    png export/.style={
        external/system call=%
        {pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource";%
         convert -density 300 -transparent white "\image.pdf" "\image.png"; rm -f "\image.pdf"},
    },
    png import/.code={%
        \tikzset{%
            /pgf/images/include external/.code={%
                % Here you can alter to whatever you want
                % \pgfexternalwidth is only available if /pgf/images/external info
                % is set
                \includegraphics%
                [width=\pgfexternalwidth,height=\pgfexternalheight]%
                {{##1}.png}%
            }%
        }%
    }%
}
\newcounter{pngeq}
\setcounter{pngeq}{0}
\newcommand{\pngequation}[1]{%
\tikzset{use png}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (eq) {
\hspace{-1.1\parindent}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
\setcounter{equation}{\number\value{pngeq}}
\begin{equation}
#1
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\stepcounter{pngeq}
}

\begin{document}
\section{Linear equation through a point given its gradient}
A very simple differential equation is to find a linear equation through a particular point $P(x_i,y_i)$ given its gradient $k_i$ (or more commonly used for lines, its slope).

\pngequation{
\frac{dy}{dx} = k_i \iff \int dy = \int k_i \cdot dx \iff y = k_i \cdot x + C
}

Plug in the initial conditions to find the particular value of the constant of integration $C$.


\pngequation{
\frac{dy}{dx} = k_i \iff \int dy = \int k_i \cdot dx \iff y = k_i \cdot x + C'
}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

For subequations you can extend the solution above along the same lines. First add an extra subequation counter that resets with the main counter:

```
\newcounter{pngsubeq}[pngeq]
```

Then define a command `\pngsubequation` that steps this counter and uses it in the numbering.

```
\newcommand{\pngsubequation}[1]{%
\tikzset{use png}
\ifnum\value{pngsubeq}=0\stepcounter{pngeq}\fi% first subequation, step main counter
\stepcounter{pngsubeq}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (eq) {
\hspace{-1.1\parindent}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{pngeq}\alph{pngsubeq}}
\begin{equation}
#1
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

To step the main counter for the subequations a hook can be added to the `subequations` environment:

```
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{subequations}{\stepcounter{pngeq}}
```

Then you can use `\begin{subequations}` with `\pngsubeqation` inside:

```
\begin{subequations}
\pngsubequation{...}

\pngsubequation{...}
\end{subequations}
```

Full code, with a feq sets of normal equations and subequations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\tikzset{%
    % Add size information to the .dpth file (png is in density not size)
    /pgf/images/external info,
    % Use the png export AND the import
    use png/.style={png export,png import},
    png export/.style={
        external/system call=%
        {pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource";%
         convert -density 300 -transparent white "\image.pdf" "\image.png"; rm -f "\image.pdf"},
    },
    png import/.code={%
        \tikzset{%
            /pgf/images/include external/.code={%
                % Here you can alter to whatever you want
                % \pgfexternalwidth is only available if /pgf/images/external info
                % is set
                \includegraphics%
                [width=\pgfexternalwidth,height=\pgfexternalheight]%
                {{##1}.png}%
            }%
        }%
    }%
}
\newcounter{pngeq}
\setcounter{pngeq}{0}
\newcounter{pngsubeq}[pngeq]
\newcommand{\pngequation}[1]{%
\tikzset{use png}
\stepcounter{pngeq}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (eq) {
\hspace{-1.1\parindent}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{pngeq}}
\begin{equation}
#1
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{subequations}{\stepcounter{pngeq}}
\newcommand{\pngsubequation}[1]{%
\tikzset{use png}
\stepcounter{pngsubeq}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (eq) {
\hspace{-1.1\parindent}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{pngeq}\alph{pngsubeq}}
\begin{equation}
#1
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}


\begin{document}
\section{Linear equation through a point given its gradient}
A very simple differential equation is to find a linear equation through a particular point $P(x_i,y_i)$ given its gradient $k_i$.

\pngequation{
\frac{dy}{dx} = k_i \iff \int dy = \int k_i \cdot dx \iff y = k_i \cdot x + C
}

Plug in the initial conditions to find the particular value of the constant of integration $C$.


\pngequation{
\frac{dy}{dx} = k_i \iff \int dy = \int k_i \cdot dx \iff y = k_i \cdot x + C'
}

A very simple differential equation is to find a linear equation through a particular point $P(x_i,y_i)$ given its gradient $k_i$.

\begin{subequations}
\pngsubequation{
\frac{dy}{dx} = k_i \iff \int dy = \int k_i \cdot dx \iff y = k_i \cdot x + C
}

Plug in the initial conditions to find the particular value of the constant of integration $C$.

\pngsubequation{
\frac{dy}{dx} = k_i \iff \int dy = \int k_i \cdot dx \iff y = k_i \cdot x + C'
}
\end{subequations}

A very simple differential equation is to find a linear equation through a particular point $P(x_i,y_i)$ given its gradient $k_i$.

\pngequation{
\frac{dy}{dx} = k_i \iff \int dy = \int k_i \cdot dx \iff y = k_i \cdot x + C
}

Plug in the initial conditions to find the particular value of the constant of integration $C$.


\pngequation{
\frac{dy}{dx} = k_i \iff \int dy = \int k_i \cdot dx \iff y = k_i \cdot x + C'
}

A very simple differential equation is to find a linear equation through a particular point $P(x_i,y_i)$ given its gradient $k_i$.

\begin{subequations}
\pngsubequation{
\frac{dy}{dx} = k_i \iff \int dy = \int k_i \cdot dx \iff y = k_i \cdot x + C
}

Plug in the initial conditions to find the particular value of the constant of integration $C$.

\pngsubequation{
\frac{dy}{dx} = k_i \iff \int dy = \int k_i \cdot dx \iff y = k_i \cdot x + C'
}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}

\tikzset{use png}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (eq) {
\hspace{-\parindent}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dx} = k_i \iff \int dy = \int k_i \cdot dx \iff y = k_i \cdot x + C
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I'll try this out as soon as possible, thanks for looking into it!

Comment: What's the most straightforward way to compiling the document using `-shell-escape` from the Texmaker GUI? Or how can I do it manually from the terminal?

Comment: @JansthcirlU see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/236648/. `-enable-write18` is the MikTeX equivalent of `-shell-escape`, on Mac or Linux you may need `-shell-escape`. For the terminal: open a terminal, navigate to the folder where your document is (using the `cd` command), then type `pdflatex -shell-escape yourfile.tex` where you schould replace `yourfile` with the actual name of your file.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it.

Comment: It looks like I get `pdf` outputs of each equation image, rather than `png` files that can be linked.

Comment: @JansthcirlU did you make sure to include `\tikzset{use png}` in the right place? Did you try this MWE, or you tried your own real document? Does the `convert` system call work? I seem to remember that `convert` (which is part of the ImageMagick programs) has a different name on Windows. You should get errors in the logs if this fails, you can also try to run the `convert ` command with the appropriate arguments in a terminal to see if the conversion actually works.

Comment: I blindly copied over your MWE to a file named `ImageEquations.tex` and compiled it using `pdflatex -enable-write18 ImageEquations.tex`. I'm not very familiar with Latex overall, so I find it hard to navigate the terminal output.

Comment: @JansthcirlU I just realized that the delete command at the end (`rm -f "\image.pdf"`) is also OS-specific, i.e., this works only on Linux and Mac. For Windows substituting this by `del "\image.pdf"` might work I think (cannot test that now).

Comment: It looks like the `png` files doesn't get created. For everything `ImageEquations-figure0` related files, I get the following file extensions: `pdf`, `md5`, `txt` and `dpth`.

Comment: @JansthcirlU then it is probably a problem with the `convert` command. In Windows probably using either only `magick` instead of `convert` or `magick convert` (so the two commands in a row) is supposed to work. Install via https://imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows if you don't have it yet.

Comment: @Marijn Very helpful ! Could you also help to suggest how to handle subequations environment using your solution ? For example, some equations 1 to 30, then 31a, 31b, then 32 to 40, then 41a, 41b ? Many thanks !

Comment: @SOUser I have added subequations to the answer.

Comment: @Marijn Is it possible to support 1 to 30, 31a, 31b, 32a, 32b ? Currently the 32a, 32b appear as 31c, 31d....

Comment: @SOUser that is a situation I did not think about indeed, when you immediately start a new set of subequations then the subequation counter is not zero so my check to increase the main counter did not work. I changed it into a hook for the `subequations` environment and removed the original check (see edit), this is more robust and also covers the multiple sets of subequations in a row.

Comment: @Marjin Many thanks ! Would you help to suggest if it is possible to match the name of the generated images as the subequations ? :D Without subequations there is offset of 1 which is not so hard to pin down. With subequations the offset is a bit hard to compute.

Comment: @Marijn Would it be possible to name the files as *** figure1.png,...., figure 32a.png, figure 32b.png for equations 1.... 32a, 32b ?

Comment: @SOUser this might be possible, I'm not sure if the equation counters are available at the time the files are written but that can probably be made to work. I don't have time now but I will try to take a look over the next couple of days.

Comment: @Marijn Based on your mwe, if I add `\tikzsetnextfilename{\jobname-eq-\arabic{pngeq}}` and `\tikzsetnextfilename{\jobname-eq-\arabic{pngeq}\alph{pngsubeq}}` before `\tikzset{use png}`, respectively, the issue of image names could be solved, which is nice enough. The whole file is shown in https://pastebin.com/3X6DYMLP. However, there appear two new gitches. One is I have to manually run pdflatex twice (the first run gives a parent pdf without equations). Two is the first run seems to run two rounds.

Comment: I tried @Marijn code and it worked perfectly on Overleaf. However, I couldn't manage to make it work on my local installation (MikTek + TexMaker), even after configuring my pdflatex with the following command inside TexMaker : ```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -enable-write18 %.tex
``` When I tried to execute the code, I got the following error : ! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "main-figure1" "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{m
ain}\input{main}";convert -density 300 -transparent white "main-figure1.pdf"