# Problem converting equations to images on Windows 10

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, equations, pdftex

My problem follows on from the question posed by JansthcirlU and from the response by Marijn ([Converting equations to images](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/594797/converting-equations-to-images/711608?noredirect=1#comment1768386_711608)). I blindly copied Marijn's first MWE and it works perfectly on Overleaf. But I can't use it on Overleaf for my own project because of the compilation timeout, so I tried on my local installation (TexLive 2023 + TexMaker) and I'm getting the following error :

LaTeX Warning: File '{main-figure0}.png' not found on input line 53.
! Package pdftex.def Error: File 'main-figure0.png' not found: using draft setting.

Equations are well converted to pdf, but the pdf are not converted into png and I have 4 differents files for each equation : `.dpth`, `.md5`, `.log` and `.pdf`. As Marijn said, since I'm on Windows, I replaced `rm -f` to `del` and `convert` to `magick` inside the MWE but it still doesn't work. I also have the latest ImageMagick release installed and when I type `where magick` in Windows' cmd, I got the right path.

What do you think is the problem ?

Edit 1 : Here is the content of my .log file :

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.2.26)  27 FEB 2024 14:11
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**main.tex
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count188
\c@section=\count189
\c@subsection=\count190
\c@subsubsection=\count191
\c@paragraph=\count192
\c@subparagraph=\count193
\c@figure=\count194
\c@table=\count195
\abovecaptionskip=\skip48
\belowcaptionskip=\skip49
\bibindent=\dimen140
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2023/05/13 v2.17o AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip50

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2021/08/26 v2.01 AMS text

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks17
\ex@=\dimen141
))
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen142
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2022/04/08 v2.04 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count196
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 234.
\uproot@=\count197
\leftroot@=\count198
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 399.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \colon on input line 410.
\classnum@=\count199
\DOTSCASE@=\count266
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 496.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 499.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 620.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box51
\strutbox@=\box52
LaTeX Info: Redefining \big on input line 722.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Big on input line 723.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bigg on input line 724.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Bigg on input line 725.
\big@size=\dimen143
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 743.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 744.
\macc@depth=\count267
LaTeX Info: Redefining \bmod on input line 905.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \pmod on input line 910.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \smash on input line 940.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \relbar on input line 970.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Relbar on input line 971.
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count268
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count269
\dspbrk@lvl=\count270
\tag@help=\toks18
\row@=\count271
\column@=\count272
\maxfields@=\count273
\andhelp@=\toks19
\eqnshift@=\dimen144
\alignsep@=\dimen145
\tagshift@=\dimen146
\tagwidth@=\dimen147
\totwidth@=\dimen148
\lineht@=\dimen149
\@envbody=\toks20
\multlinegap=\skip51
\multlinetaggap=\skip52
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks21
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2953.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2954.
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz.sty
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgf.sty
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.sty
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
\pgfutil@everybye=\toks22
\pgfutil@tempdima=\dimen150
\pgfutil@tempdimb=\dimen151
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-latex.def
\pgfutil@abb=\box53
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfrcs.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/pgf.revision.tex)
Package: pgfrcs 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))
Package: pgf 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.sty
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2021/09/16 v1.2d Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2022/05/29 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks23
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2022/03/10 v1.4e Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 2021/08/11 v1.11 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 107.

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2022/09/22 v1.2b Graphics/color driver for pdftex
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen152
\Gin@req@width=\dimen153
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.sty
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys.code.tex
Package: pgfsys 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
\pgfkeys@pathtoks=\toks24
\pgfkeys@temptoks=\toks25

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeyslibraryfiltered.co
de.tex
\pgfkeys@tmptoks=\toks26
))
\pgf@x=\dimen154
\pgf@y=\dimen155
\pgf@xa=\dimen156
\pgf@ya=\dimen157
\pgf@xb=\dimen158
\pgf@yb=\dimen159
\pgf@xc=\dimen160
\pgf@yc=\dimen161
\pgf@xd=\dimen162
\pgf@yd=\dimen163
\w@pgf@writea=\write3
\r@pgf@reada=\read2
\c@pgf@counta=\count274
\c@pgf@countb=\count275
\c@pgf@countc=\count276
\c@pgf@countd=\count277
\t@pgf@toka=\toks27
\t@pgf@tokb=\toks28
\t@pgf@tokc=\toks29
\pgf@sys@id@count=\count278
 (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgf.cfg
File: pgf.cfg 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
Driver file for pgf: pgfsys-pdftex.def

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-pdftex.def
File: pgfsys-pdftex.def 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsys-common-pdf.def
File: pgfsys-common-pdf.def 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)))
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex
File: pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfsyssoftpath@smallbuffer@items=\count279
\pgfsyssoftpath@bigbuffer@items=\count280
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/systemlayer/pgfsysprotocol.code.tex
File: pgfsysprotocol.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
Package: xcolor 2023/11/15 v3.01 LaTeX color extensions (UK)

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
File: color.cfg 2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
)
Package xcolor Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 274.

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx)
Package xcolor Info: Model `cmy' substituted by `cmy0' on input line 1350.
Package xcolor Info: Model `hsb' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1354.
Package xcolor Info: Model `RGB' extended on input line 1366.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HTML' substituted by `rgb' on input line 1368.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Hsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1369.
Package xcolor Info: Model `tHsb' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1370.
Package xcolor Info: Model `HSB' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1371.
Package xcolor Info: Model `Gray' substituted by `gray' on input line 1372.
Package xcolor Info: Model `wave' substituted by `hsb' on input line 1373.
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcore.code.tex
Package: pgfcore 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
\pgfmath@dimen=\dimen164
\pgfmath@count=\count281
\pgfmath@box=\box54
\pgfmath@toks=\toks30
\pgfmath@stack@operand=\toks31
\pgfmath@stack@operation=\toks32
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric
.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.t
ex)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.co
de.tex)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.te
x)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithm
etics.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex
\c@pgfmathroundto@lastzeros=\count282
))
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfint.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepoints.code.tex
File: pgfcorepoints.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@picminx=\dimen165
\pgf@picmaxx=\dimen166
\pgf@picminy=\dimen167
\pgf@picmaxy=\dimen168
\pgf@pathminx=\dimen169
\pgf@pathmaxx=\dimen170
\pgf@pathminy=\dimen171
\pgf@pathmaxy=\dimen172
\pgf@xx=\dimen173
\pgf@xy=\dimen174
\pgf@yx=\dimen175
\pgf@yy=\dimen176
\pgf@zx=\dimen177
\pgf@zy=\dimen178
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.cod
e.tex
File: pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@path@lastx=\dimen179
\pgf@path@lasty=\dimen180
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathusage.code.te
x
File: pgfcorepathusage.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@shorten@end@additional=\dimen181
\pgf@shorten@start@additional=\dimen182
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorescopes.code.tex
File: pgfcorescopes.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfpic=\box55
\pgf@hbox=\box56
\pgf@layerbox@main=\box57
\pgf@picture@serial@count=\count283
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoregraphicstate.code
.tex
File: pgfcoregraphicstate.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgflinewidth=\dimen183
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransformations.c
ode.tex
File: pgfcoretransformations.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@pt@x=\dimen184
\pgf@pt@y=\dimen185
\pgf@pt@temp=\dimen186
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorequick.code.tex
File: pgfcorequick.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreobjects.code.tex
File: pgfcoreobjects.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathprocessing.co
de.tex
File: pgfcorepathprocessing.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorearrows.code.tex
File: pgfcorearrows.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfarrowsep=\dimen187
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreshade.code.tex
File: pgfcoreshade.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@max=\dimen188
\pgf@sys@shading@range@num=\count284
\pgf@shadingcount=\count285
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreimage.code.tex
File: pgfcoreimage.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoreexternal.code.tex
File: pgfcoreexternal.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfexternal@startupbox=\box58
) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorelayers.code.tex
File: pgfcorelayers.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcoretransparency.code
.tex
File: pgfcoretransparency.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepatterns.code.tex
File: pgfcorepatterns.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorerdf.code.tex
File: pgfcorerdf.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
))) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleshapes.code.te
x
File: pgfmoduleshapes.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfnodeparttextbox=\box59
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmoduleplot.code.tex
File: pgfmoduleplot.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-0-65.st
y
Package: pgfcomp-version-0-65 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@nodesepstart=\dimen189
\pgf@nodesepend=\dimen190
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/compatibility/pgfcomp-version-1-18.st
y
Package: pgfcomp-version-1-18 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgffor.sty
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.sty
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/math/pgfmath.sty
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
Package: pgffor 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgffor@iter=\dimen191
\pgffor@skip=\dimen192
\pgffor@stack=\toks33
\pgffor@toks=\toks34
))
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/tikz.code.tex
Package: tikz 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/libraries/pgflibraryplothandlers.co
de.tex
File: pgflibraryplothandlers.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgf@plot@mark@count=\count286
\pgfplotmarksize=\dimen193
)
\tikz@lastx=\dimen194
\tikz@lasty=\dimen195
\tikz@lastxsaved=\dimen196
\tikz@lastysaved=\dimen197
\tikz@lastmovetox=\dimen198
\tikz@lastmovetoy=\dimen199
\tikzleveldistance=\dimen256
\tikzsiblingdistance=\dimen257
\tikz@figbox=\box60
\tikz@figbox@bg=\box61
\tikz@tempbox=\box62
\tikz@tempbox@bg=\box63
\tikztreelevel=\count287
\tikznumberofchildren=\count288
\tikznumberofcurrentchild=\count289
\tikz@fig@count=\count290

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/modules/pgfmodulematrix.code.tex
File: pgfmodulematrix.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
\pgfmatrixcurrentrow=\count291
\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn=\count292
\pgf@matrix@numberofcolumns=\count293
)
\tikz@expandcount=\count294

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzli
brarytopaths.code.tex
File: tikzlibrarytopaths.code.tex 2023-01-15 v3.1.10 (3.1.10)
)))
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pgf/frontendlayer/libraries/tikzlibraryex
ternal.code.tex
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty
Package: iftex 2022/02/03 v1.0f TeX engine tests
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2023-12-04 v1.26 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty
Package: atveryend-ltx 2020/08/19 v1.0a Emulation of the original atveryend pac
kage
with kernel methods
)
(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzex
ternalshared.code.tex))
\openout3 = `main.auxlock'.

\c@pngeq=\count295

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def
File: l3backend-pdftex.def 2024-02-20 L3 backend support: PDF output (pdfTeX)
\l__color_backend_stack_int=\count296
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box64
)
(./main.aux)
\openout1 = `main.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 47.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 47.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 47.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 47.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 47.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 47.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 47.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 47.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 47.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 47.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 47.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 47.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 47.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 47.
 (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count297
\scratchdimen=\dimen258
\scratchbox=\box65
\nofMPsegments=\count298
\nofMParguments=\count299
\everyMPshowfont=\toks35
\MPscratchCnt=\count300
\MPscratchDim=\dimen259
\MPnumerator=\count301
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count302
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks36
) (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
Package epstopdf-base Info: Redefining graphics rule for `.eps' on input line 4
85.

(c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
===== Image 'main-figure0' is up-to-date. ======

LaTeX Warning: File `{main-figure0}.png' not found on input line 53.


! Package pdftex.def Error: File `main-figure0.png' not found: using draft sett
ing.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.53 }
      
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


Overfull \hbox (5.2577pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 53--54
[][]
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 53--54

 []

===== Image 'main-figure1' is up-to-date. ======

LaTeX Warning: File `{main-figure1}.png' not found on input line 60.


! Package pdftex.def Error: File `main-figure1.png' not found: using draft sett
ing.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.60 }
      
Try typing  <return>  to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type  X <return>  to quit.


Overfull \hbox (5.2577pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 60--61
[][]
 []


Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 60--61

 []

[1

{c:/texlive/2023/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./main.aux)
 ***********
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
 ***********
 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 13144 strings out of 474136
 272862 string characters out of 5748496
 1927190 words of memory out of 5000000
 35268 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 559296 words of font info for 41 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 102i,5n,107p,541b,241s stack positions out of 10000i,1000n,20000p,200000b,200000s
<c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb><c:/tex
live/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi10.pfb><c:/texlive/2023
/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmmi7.pfb><c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dis
t/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb><c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/fonts/ty
pe1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmtt10.pfb>
Output written on main.pdf (1 page, 57436 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 36 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 22 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 13 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Edit 2 : I've partially solved the problem. It seems that Ghostscript is needed in order to rasterize vector files such as PDF (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32466112/imagemagick-convert-pdf-to-jpeg-failedtoexecutecommand-gswin32c-exe-pdfdel). Now, when I try to manually convert a .pdf equation (main-figure0.pdf for example) using `magick -density 300 "main-figure0.pdf" "main-figure0.png"` in cmd, it's working. But the MWE still doesn't work, so it seems that `magick` command can't be executed inside a LaTex script and I don't know why. However, when I manually converted the .pdf files to .png files, the script ran smoothly. Here is the actual MWE with modifications to work on Windows :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\tikzset{%
    % Add size information to the .dpth file (png is in density not size)
    /pgf/images/external info,
    % Use the png export AND the import
    use png/.style={png export,png import},
    png export/.style={
        external/system call=%
        {pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource";%
         magick -density 300 "\image.pdf" "\image.png"; del "\image.pdf"},
    },
    png import/.code={%
        \tikzset{%
            /pgf/images/include external/.code={%
                % Here you can alter to whatever you want
                % \pgfexternalwidth is only available if /pgf/images/external info
                % is set
                \includegraphics%
                [width=\pgfexternalwidth,height=\pgfexternalheight]%
                {{##1}.png}%
            }%
        }%
    }%
}
\newcounter{pngeq}
\setcounter{pngeq}{0}
\newcommand{\pngequation}[1]{%
\tikzset{use png}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (eq) {
\hspace{-1.1\parindent}\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}%
\setcounter{equation}{\number\value{pngeq}}
\begin{equation}
#1
\end{equation}
\end{minipage}
};
\end{tikzpicture}%
\stepcounter{pngeq}
}

\begin{document}
\section{Linear equation through a point given its gradient}
A very simple differential equation is to find a linear equation through a particular point $P(x_i,y_i)$ given its gradient $k_i$ (or more commonly used for lines, its slope).

\pngequation{
\frac{dy}{dx} = k_i \iff \int dy = \int k_i \cdot dx \iff y = k_i \cdot x + C
}

Plug in the initial conditions to find the particular value of the constant of integration $C$.


\pngequation{
\frac{dy}{dx} = k_i \iff \int dy = \int k_i \cdot dx \iff y = k_i \cdot x + C'
}
\end{document}
```

If anyone can spot why the script does't want to convert .pdf file to .png file, I'm all ears.

Comment: Are you compiling with shell-escape enabled? Can you show the first couple of lines of your .log file?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Yes I enable shell-escape, here is the first lines of my .log file : 

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.2.26)  27 FEB 2024 14:11
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.

I also tried with the command line (also with shell-escape) and I got the same result.

Comment: Good. Can you show your complete .log file in your question?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I'll edit the question to show my entire .log file

Comment: Thanks! I can't see anything which stands out. Maybe if a windows user sees your question, they can see something.

Comment: If you typed `where convert` but changed `convert` to `magick`, something seems awry. If `magick` is the right command to use on Windows, I'd assume you'd want `where magick`. On the other hand, if `convert` is available, maybe you should be using that?

Comment: @cfr You're totally right, but it doesn't change the problem. Indeed, the `where convert` was not refering to ImageMagick path but to Windows's convert. However, I tried `where magick`and it showed the ImageMagick command path. So `magick` seems to be the right command here on Windows.

Comment: Hopefully somebody on Windows will happen by. The code compiles OK for me, but 'install Linux' probably isn't the answer you're looking for :).

Comment: @cfr Thanks, I found the beginning of an answer and I edited my question. Again, it seems that it is a problem related to Windows.